# Large object on ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I am storing object of a class on a ViewState. It has 3 string variables. But when ever one string gets larger (more than 400 chars) Pagination stops working.

I have tried so many things but no luck.

So I need to think of another Session Management method?

```
public class Productx
{
    public bool check { get; set; } // ForMultiProduct Page - Selected or not
    public string imagePathSmall { get; set; }
    public string imagePathLarge { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RatingCount { get; set; }
    public string SetName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string KeyWords { get; set; }
    public int FavourCount { get; set; }
}

public List<Productx> ArticleList
{
    get
    {
        if (this.ViewState["ArticleList"] != null)
        {
            return (List<Productx>)(this.ViewState["ArticleList"]);
        }
        return new List<Productx>();
    }
    set { this.ViewState["ArticleList"] = value; }
}

List<Productx> al = new List<Productx>();
foreach (DataRow dr in tblProducts.Rows)
{
    Productx a = new Productx();
    a.check = false;                      
    a.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"].ToString());                        
    a.RatingCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RATING_COUNT_BY_CAT"].ToString());                                               
    string s = dr["KEY_WORDS"].ToString();                       
    a.KeyWords = s;                        
    a.FavourCount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["FAVORITE_COUNT"].ToString());                       
    al.Add(a);
}
if (al.Count > 0) ArticleList = al;
```

Comment: could you please provide some code examples?

Comment: 400 chars it NOT a large object.